# Combine two state flows into new state flow

Tags: kotlin, collections, kotlin-flow

I have two state flows. Is it possible to combine them and get new state flow? Logically it should be possible because both state flows have initials values, but as I see combine function returns just Flow and not StateFlow.

Comment: I think you find some this https://medium.com/better-programming/learn-how-to-combine-kotlin-flows-317849a71d3e

Comment: _Why_ do you specifically need a `StateFlow`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman In some places I need just to read current value without collecting of it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So far I created function:

```
fun <T1, T2, R> combineState(
        flow1: StateFlow<T1>,
        flow2: StateFlow<T2>,
        scope: CoroutineScope = GlobalScope,
        sharingStarted: SharingStarted = SharingStarted.Eagerly,
        transform: (T1, T2) -> R
): StateFlow<R> = combine(flow1, flow2) {
    o1, o2 -> transform.invoke(o1, o2)
}.stateIn(scope, sharingStarted, transform.invoke(flow1.value, flow2.value))
```

Comment: Can you show how you use this in code?  Doesn't seem to work for me

Answer (score 24):

You could use the `combine` operator, and then use the `stateIn` function for the `Flow` that results from that.

From the `stateIn` [documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/state-in.html) in the kotlinx coroutines repository:

The `stateIn` function "Converts a *cold* `Flow` into a *hot* `StateFlow` that is started in the given coroutine scope, sharing the most recently emitted value from a single running instance of the upstream flow with multiple downstream subscribers."

It's signature, as of the time of writing this, is:

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.stateIn(
  scope: CoroutineScope,
  started: SharingStarted,
  initialValue: T
): StateFlow<T> (source)
```

So you should be able to do whatever transformations you need to your `Flow`s, including combining them, and then ultimately use `stateIn` to convert them back to a `StateFlow`.

It could look something like this (perhaps creating a Scrabble game point calculator):

```
val wordFlow = MutableStateFlow("Hi")
val pointFlow = MutableStateFlow(5)

val stateString = wordFlow.combine(pointFlow) { word, points ->
    "$word is worth $points points"
}.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, "Default is worth 0 points")
```

`stateString` would be of type `StateFlow<String>`, and you have successfully combined the two other `StateFlows` into one `StateFlow`.

Comment: And as always, it is about 5 second after I post this that I realize you answered your own question by using `stateIn`. Alas, I shall leave the description for posterity.

Answer (score 4):

Above mentioned solutions are using `stateIn()` with `GlobalScope` and policy as `Eagerly` which means ***these StateFlows will never stop being observed once created which can lead to the issues***.

I already have mentioned [**details in this blog**](https://blog.shreyaspatil.dev/combining-stateflows-and-transforming-it-into-a-stateflow). Instead, create a separate class which derives a new `StateFlow`:

```
private class TransformedStateFlow<T>(
    private val getValue: () -> T,
    private val flow: Flow<T>
) : StateFlow<T> {
    
    override val replayCache: List<T> get() = listOf(value)
    override val value: T get() = getValue()

    override suspend fun collect(collector: FlowCollector<T>): Nothing =
        coroutineScope { flow.stateIn(this).collect(collector) }
}

/**
 * Returns [StateFlow] from [flow] having initial value from calculation of [getValue]
 */
fun <T> stateFlow(
    getValue: () -> T,
    flow: Flow<T>
): StateFlow<T> = TransformedStateFlow(getValue, flow)

/**
 * Combines all [stateFlows] and transforms them into another [StateFlow] with [transform]
 */
inline fun <reified T, R> combineStates(
    vararg stateFlows: StateFlow<T>,
    crossinline transform: (Array<T>) -> R
): StateFlow<R> = stateFlow(
    getValue = { transform(stateFlows.map { it.value }.toTypedArray()) },
    flow = combine(*stateFlows) { transform(it) }
)

/**
 * Variant of [combineStates] for combining 3 state flows
 */
inline fun <reified T1, reified T2, reified T3, R> combineStates(
    flow1: StateFlow<T1>,
    flow2: StateFlow<T2>,
    flow3: StateFlow<T3>,
    crossinline transform: (T1, T2, T3) -> R
) = combineStates(flow1, flow2, flow3) { (t1, t2, t3) ->
    transform(
        t1 as T1,
        t2 as T2,
        t3 as T3
    )
}

// Other variants for combining N StateFlows
```

After this, you can implement it in your use case. For example:

```
private val isLoading = MutableStateFlow(false)
private val loggedInUser = MutableStateFlow<User?>(null)
private val error = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)

// Combining these states to form a LoginState
val state: StateFlow<LoginState> = combineStates(isLoading, loggedInUser, error) { loading, user, errorMessage ->
  LoginState(loading, user, errorMessage)
}
```

***This approach is safe than other mentioned approaches since it'll only listen to the `StateFlow` updates when actually it's being collected (inside consumer's Coroutine scope)***

Answer (score 1):

Similar solution to @Nikola Despotoski, but in a form of an extension function

```
/**
 * Combines two [StateFlow]s into a single [StateFlow]
 */
fun <T1, T2, R> StateFlow<T1>.combineState(
  flow2: StateFlow<T2>,
  scope: CoroutineScope = GlobalScope,
  sharingStarted: SharingStarted = SharingStarted.Eagerly,
  transform: (T1, T2) -> R
): StateFlow<R> = combine(this, flow2) { o1, o2 -> transform.invoke(o1, o2) }
  .stateIn(scope, sharingStarted, transform.invoke(this.value, flow2.value))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Combine n state flows

```
@Suppress("CHANGING_ARGUMENTS_EXECUTION_ORDER_FOR_NAMED_VARARGS")
inline fun <reified T, R> combineStateFlow(
    vararg flows: StateFlow<T>,
    scope: CoroutineScope = GlobalScope,
    sharingStarted: SharingStarted = SharingStarted.Eagerly,
    crossinline transform: (Array<T>) -> R
): StateFlow<R> = combine(flows = flows) {
    transform.invoke(it)
}.stateIn(
    scope = scope,
    started = sharingStarted,
    initialValue = transform.invoke(flows.map {
        it.value
    }.toTypedArray())
)
```

---

### Using:

```
data class A(val a: String)
data class B(val b: Int)

private val test1 = MutableStateFlow(A("a"))
private val test2 = MutableStateFlow(B(2))
@Suppress("CHANGING_ARGUMENTS_EXECUTION_ORDER_FOR_NAMED_VARARGS")
private val _isValidForm = combineStateFlow(
    flows = arrayOf(test1, test2),
    scope = viewModelScope
) { combinedFlows: Array<Any> ->
    combinedFlows.map {
        val doSomething = when (it) {
            is A -> true
            is B -> false
            else -> false
        }
    }
}
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/Coronel-B/910a564a07156d0f1e7f488bcf1bbc31)

Answer (score 0):

A `CoroutineScope` is not needed to combine two `StateFlows`, if you have a initial value:

```
fun <T1, T2, R> combine(flow: StateFlow<T1>, flow2: StateFlow<T2>, initialValue: R, transform: suspend (a: T1, b: T2) -> R): StateFlow<R> {
    return object : StateFlow<R> {
        private val mutex = Mutex()
        override var value: R = initialValue

        override val replayCache: List<R> get() = listOf(value)

        override suspend fun collect(collector: FlowCollector<R>): Nothing {
            combine(flow, flow2, transform)
                .onStart { emit(initialValue) }
                .collect {
                    mutex.withLock {
                        value = it
                        collector.emit(it)
                    }
                }
            error("This exception is needed to 'return' Nothing. It won't be thrown (collection of StateFlow will never end)")
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
val letters = MutableStateFlow("A")
val numbers = MutableStateFlow(0)
val lettersAndNumbers: StateFlow<String> = combine(letters, numbers, "initial") { a, b -> a + b }
```

You can check the usage with this [kotlin playground demo](https://pl.kotl.in/vqu8jWzb2)

Answer (score 0):

you need a "merge" to combine two state flows.

Here how I did:

```
 viewModelScope.launch {
        merge(biometricsHelper.biometricsState, loginStore.sessionFlow).collect { result ->
                if (result is Session) {
                    uiStateInternal.update {
                        it.copy(
                            loggedIn = result.loggedIn,
                            showFingerprintButton = it.biometricsState == BiometricsState.ENABLED && result.loggedIn
                        )
                    }
                } else if (result is BiometricsState) {
                    uiStateInternal.update {
                        it.copy(
                            biometricsState = result,
                            showFingerprintButton = result == BiometricsState.ENABLED && it.loggedIn
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

*"combine" is for grouping the results of multiple flows into a single object. To simply create a new Flow that passes through the individual emissions from each one independently, merge is the correct operator to use here.*
Check out this discussion here: https://slack-chats.kotlinlang.org/t/489000/how-to-combine-two-sharedflow-s-into-flow-that-emits-when-ei

Answer (score -2):

Use `combine` operator, it takes two flows and a transformation function to combine the results from both flows.

```kotlin
 val int = MutableStateFlow(2)
 val double = MutableStateFlow(1.8)
 int.combine(double){ i, d ->
            i + d             
 }.collect(::println)
```

Comment: I need specifically StateFlow, but this function returns Flow

Comment: This now errors in the IDE says "Not enough information to infer type variable R" also it is asking for a transform.  Still new to this so please explain or modify your answer if the library has updated. Thank you!