# How to expose StateFlow but start and stop underlying Flow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow, kotlin-coroutines

I have a class that receives data from the device sensors. I've wrapped the callback inside a `callbackFlow` in order to get a `Flow`.

```
private var sensorFlow: Flow<AccelerationState> = callbackFlow {
        val listener: SensorEventListener = object : SensorEventListener {
            override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {
              ...
            }

            override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor?, accuracy: Int) {
              ...
            }
        }
        sensorManager.registerListener(listener, accelSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)

        awaitClose() {
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(listener, accelSensor)
        }
    }
```

Ideally want to expose a `StateFlow` so I've done this:

```
 sensorFlow.stateIn(
        scope = scope,
        started = WhileSubscribed(5000),
        initialValue = AccelerationState(0,0,0))
```

I want to be able to pause/resume the sensor readings which I would normally do by registering/unregistering the listener. My understanding is that I have to stop listening to the flow and then restart it again if I want to have that effect.
I've tried using `takeWhile { isGathering }` but after the `Flow` is killed it can't be restarted again. And redeclaring the `StateFlow` does nothing as the rest of the app has the previous reference stored.

How can I expose a `StateFlow` but be able to change the underlying `Flow` from which it's created?

Edit: The `StateFlow` is then simply referenced in a `ViewModel` and can then be accessed by the View:

```
val sensorStateFlow = sensorDataRepository.sensorStateFlow
```

Comment: I think your code already does what you're describing. `SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed` will stop and restart the underlying flow as listeners come and go. Can you share the code that you're using to consume the `StateFlow`? Perhaps that's where your problem lies.

Comment: Hi @Sam Thank you for taking the time to reply. I've edited the answer. It's just propagated to the `ViewModel`.
I have a button that pauses the sensor. The `isGathering` flag is then updated in the Sensor class and finishes the `Flow`. Setting `isGathering` back to true doesn't do anything. 
Either way, I want to be able to restart the `Flow` completely since I need to be able to change the parameter on `registerListener` (the sample rate).
Basically keep the `StateFlow` reference constant but change the underlying `Flow` that provides the data.

Comment: Did you ever come to a solution for this problem? I'm new to coroutine and flows and have been trying to figure out the same.

Comment: @Keith The solution would be to generally avoid `StateFlow` at the data/domain layer. Make sure your repositories expose `Flow` or functions that return `Flow` and only `.stateIn` in e.g. a ViewModel

Comment: Thanks for the response @AlexV. and the context! I've still been playing around with the idea and have run into some other potential solutions which I'll link here for the curious: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72783757/5162097 and https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2631

Answer (score -2):

What if you were to use a flow of flows?

First, create a `MutableStateFlow` that will hold the "current" flow. Its initial value is just an empty flow.

```kotlin
val currentFlow = MutableStateFlow<Flow<T>>(emptyFlow())
```

Then, launch the `StateFlow` that subscribers will consume. This is based on a concatenated flow that always collects the latest flow that was emitted by `currentFlow`.

```kotlin
val stateFlow = currentFlow.flatMapLatest { it }.stateIn(scope)
```

Initially, the `stateFlow` is empty (and suspends, because it doesn't have an initial value). To start it, you can set the value of `currentFlow`:

```kotlin
currentFlow.value = createNewSensorFlow()
```

The values from the sensor flow will then be collected and available via the `stateFlow`. Setting a new value for `currentFlow` will cause the concatenated `stateFlow` to stop listening to (and terminate) the previous flow and start collecting from the new one instead. To pause the sensor you can set the value back to an empty flow:

```kotlin
currentFlow.value = emptyFlow()
```

You could still use `SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed` when launching the state flow, to ensure that the listeners aren't active when there are no subscribers. If you do that, the "current" flow will simply be collected again when new subscribers arrive. Because you're using a callback flow, that should work fine, and will just initialise the flow again to create a new listener.

---

As a simplification, if the sample rate is the only thing you need to change, consider something like this:

```kotlin
val sampleRate = MutableStateFlow<Int?>(null)
val stateFlow = sampleRate.flatMapLatest { sampleRate ->
    if (sampleRate == null) {
        emptyFlow()
    } else {
        createSensorFlow(sampleRate)
    }
}.stateIn(scope)
```

Here, instead of setting `currentFlow`, we just set `sampleRate.value` to whatever we want. Each time it's changed, the "current flow" (which is now created as part of `flatMapLatest`) is replaced. We set `sampleRate.value` to `null` to emit an empty flow and thereby pause the sensor.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this. It does indeed seem like it will work.
There's a slightly simpler solution: set the whole class as a listener and manually set the `StateFlows` value to the last value received (which is what I did previously).
My understanding was that there might be a more straightforward way to do this, since `callbackFlow` is what is recommended when dealing with, well callbacks.

I will definitely give this one a try though. Thanks again!

Comment: What in the world is `emptyFlow()`??